# Why is Etherscan not broadcasting my transaction even though it returns both OK and the transaction hash?

Tags: broadcast, etherscan

I had a raw transaction hash and I used the etherscan.io API (https://etherscan.io/apis#proxy) to broadcast it. My sending address is *0xa126336ed508dd19e40842d048b79245233a6e93*

I used the following API call:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_sendRawTransaction&hex=0xf904808000831cfde080&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

Naturally, I filled in my own Api token and my own raw transaction hash. After I first broadcast it, it returned to me the following OK result:

```
{ 
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    result: '0xbdb8c333b78af7e71c5646bde02760691efeb719970fb9753dbb154a08153200',
    id: 1
}
```

Usually when you broadcast something, it shows up in the Transaction List under an address as status *(pending)*. However, it did not show up on Etherscan when I searched for this transaction hash written in the 'result' property.

I tried to broadcast it again after a few minutes, still nothing. Then on the third try it suddenly showed up and was confirmed after a few minutes.

I've had this with multiple transaction so far. There were also times where I waited for an hour and it didn't appear in the list. Then when I broadcast the exact same raw transaction hash it instantly showed up in the transaction list. So this tells me that my call wasn't just delayed either, Etherscan did not register my broadcast, even though it returned an OK signal (because it would be statistically near impossible for it to show up exactly at the moment I try again after an hour, multiple times).

So my solution now is to keep broadcasting not until I get an **OK** signal, but until I get an **error**. Because once Etherscan registers your transaction and you broadcast again right after, it returns an error with the message "already known". And if you wait a little longer until it's registered on Etherscan, it returns an error with "nonce too low". Both of these errors are confirmations that my transaction broadcast successfully.

What is this problem? Is it a known problem? Is it just Etherscan or something with the Ethereum network in general?